# How to make an item drop in a random direction?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

On my Minecraft server, I have a mini game that requires items (tnt and redstone blocks) to be dropped in a random direction, a bit like dispensers. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What restriction prevents you from using a dispenser?

Comment: By random direction do you mean the item must have a random velocity, like falling sand?

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do, and doesn't even need command blocks.

Place the dispenser with the items you want in the ground facing up. Then place a block (I recommend using glass) on top of it. When the dispenser shoots, the item gets stuck and flies in a random direction.

Note that you can put the dispenser a block lower if you want. Also, to make the items shoot farther, place blocks around the block above the dispenser.

Answer (score -2):

you could have a complexe seems to be random pattern like this is by % 1 70 360 2 6 4  9 7 5 3 8 47 5 8 6 8 5 8 65  5 7 5 8 6 4 90 8 6 56 36 6 57 6 76 76 9 1

something like that

Comment: But how would this be implimented into his creation?